# How to update LG c-900 Windows phone from 7.0 to 7.5?

Tags: windows-phone-7

we are having LG c-900 AT & T windows phone 7.How to update it to 7.5?
In zune i am getting 7.0.7392.0 updation is available.How to update 7.5 in my phone?

Comment: Just run all the updates available in Zune. It probably takes more than one update, i.e. it first needs to go to 7.0.xxx before the update for 7.5 is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an LG c-900 with v7.5. Just open Zune and connect it with your phone and it will automatically start upgrading to 7.5.

If your phone has an early version of v7, the first message you'll see in Zune under UPDATE IN PROGRESS will show 7.0.7392.0.  When all the steps for that version are complete, another update will start with no description.  On about the 4th update, you'll see the message that you're getting a major update to Windows Phone 7.5.

If not, try it manually.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Manually how to update 7.0 to 7.5? .please clear me ...while connecting  to zune i have only 7.0.7392 updation is seeing ...

Comment: Open Zune
Go parameter
then your Tel
upgrade(mise a jour)
and you upgrade your tel